# Yield from within a nedb callback

Tags: node.js, koa, nedb

I have a koa based app where I want to write data to nedb.
The problem is shown in the following short snippet.

```
app.use(router.get('/', function*(){
  db.insert(doc, function(err,data){
     // can't yield here because the callback is not a generator
  }
}));
```

I tried the following with thunkify as per the documentation at https://github.com/tj/node-thunkify:

```
var insert = thunkify(db.insert);
app.use(router.get('/', function* (){
   yield insert(doc)
}))
```

but I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
  at Datastore.insert (/home/app/node_modules/nedb/lib/datastore.js:374:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/thunkify/index.js:43:12)
  at /home/app/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:136:8
  at Object.thunkToPromise (/home/app/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:13
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there is https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-nedb which also uses thunkify but works :-).